# Attempting to install nginx via chef-solo into vagrant results in "NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: chef-infra

I have a a project directory

```
/
  VagrantFile
  /cookbooks
    /nginx
      ..
```

In `VagrantFile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "mediapop"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-vagrant-amd64-disk1.box"

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "nginx"
  end
end
```

I run `vagrant up` and get:

```
$ vagrant halt && vagrant up
[default] Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2201.
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2201 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
[default] Running provisioner: VagrantPlugins::Chef::Provisioner::ChefSolo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2013-03-22T09:16:26+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.12.0 ***
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[nginx]"] from JSON
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[nginx]]
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [nginx]
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vagrant-ubuntu-quantal-64
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-03-22T09:16:27+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

The nginx directory is from cloning https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace from `Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out` please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue was the version of chef that was on the virtual machine that disliked some logging setting and so I needed to upgrade Chef on the node, as well as upgrade ruby as a separate issue as `gem install` was failing.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo gem install chef
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, I'm working on adding a bash file that checks if you have the omnibus install of chef and if not installs it. It's not perfectly working yet, but I feel I'm close and it should solve your problem.

In your Vagrant file above your call to chef uncomment this line:

`config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrapvm.sh"`

Then create the `bootstrapvm.sh` file. This should run before your chef calls and all it will do is install the omnibus version (and latest version) of chef.

```
#! /bin/bash
apt-get install -y curl libcurl3
if ! [ -x /usr/bin/chef-solo ] ; then
  curl -L --insecure https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
fi
```

**Note:** that the curl command line I got directly from Opscode site and may be different for your system. Refer to the site for the proper line.